# BCNF Decomposition, when to stop decomposing?

Tags: database, database-schema, bcnf

I'm having difficulties understanding BCNF decomposition.

If I have:

```
R=(A,B,C)

FDs: AB -> C, C -> B
```

Computing the closure, I have concluded that the minimal  keys are {AB} and {AC}.

```
Therefore, 
   AB --> C is NOT in BCNF violation because AB is a key
   C --> B IS in violation because C is not a key.

I decompose C --> B like this

R1 = Closure of C = (C,B)
R2 = (A,C)
```

Im unsure how to proceed from here. If it needs to be further decomposed, what do I need to do? If I am supposed to end here, how do you know when to stop decomposing?

Answer (score 0):

> Computing the closure, I have concluded that the minimal keys are {AB} and {AC}.

The candidate keys of R are {AB} and {AC}.

You decompose R into these two relations, and you *identify all the candidate keys in each of those relations*.

- R<sub>1</sub> {**AB** -> C}
- R<sub>2</sub> {**C** -> B}

The only candidate key to R<sub>1</sub> is {AB}.

The only candidate key to R<sub>2</sub> is {C}. The attribute {C} is not a key in R, but it *is* a key in R<sub>2</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

R1 and R2 are when you stop. After the decomposition you identify the keys and the functional dependencies in the new relations. The key in R1 is C (with FB: C -> B, no BCNF violation), the key in R2 is AC (no BCNF violation either).

Answer (score 0):

Write the closure for `AB->C` and `C->B`:

```
{A,B}+ = {A, B, C} 
{C}+= {C, B}
```

A+B is a superkey hence it is not violating `BCNF`. So we use the violating FD `(C->B)` to do the decomposition.

```
{A, B, C} - {B, C} = {A}
```

Then add left side of `C->B` to `{A}` and will have `{A, C}` and `{B, C}`
Hence we decompose the `R(A, B, C)` into `R(B, C)` and `R(A, C)`.